# Supremum and infimum for this set - help needed

Tags: real-analysis, functions

[image]

what is the set S bounded by? how do I do these questions? can someone please show me an exemplar solution that I could follow - thank you

Comment: the set is not bounded above while it is bounded below by zero. To show uniqueness of supremum, consider a set has two supremums $S_1$ and $S_2$ such that (if not $S_1 \neq S_2$) either $S_1 > S_2$ (show $S_2$ cannot be supremum) or $S_1 < S_2$ (show $S_1
$ cannot be supremum)

Answer (score 1):

For part (a), notice the even terms (i.e., when $n$ is even) go to infinity, so there is no upper bound, let alone a supremum. Now when $n$ is odd we get the sequence $$2^{-1},2^{-3},2^{-5},...$$ which I'm sure you can see that the limit will be $0$, and it is not hard to show that this will be the infimum. Basically, the argument goes: $0$ is clearly a lower bound. If it were the not the greatest such one, but rather $K>0$ were the infimum, we could produce something in the set, i.e., some $2^{-a}$, that will be less than $K$, contradiction. I leave it to you to flesh out the details.

For part (b), see experimentX's comment on your question; assuming there exist two suprema leads to an immediate contradiction, since one will have to be greater than the other.